# GrandParent-Parent-Child logic in Excel /VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to implement a Grandparent-Parent-Child kind of logic in Excel/VBA. But not sure what is the best approach?

### Example

I get below details from an Excel addin, so I have to use Child output and parent in some cases.

Please note that at first instance, I would not have idea if a given ticker will have parent-child relationship. Only by digging further, I will get all details. In some case, I get Parent child, and other cases GrandParent - Parent -> Child relationship.

So kind of I am looking for recursive logic which drill down and pull all details.

```
1) GrandParent :- .ABC had two childerns, ( 1,2)

    .ABC -> .ABC1 , ABC2

2) Parent : ABC1 and ABC2 has 6 child each
            .ABC1 -> Child1, Child2, Child3,.. Child6
            .ABC2 -> Child1, Child2, Child3,.. Child6

3) Child : Child1, Child2, Child3,.. Child6 can have children too... 



       .ABC 
      /   \
   .ABC1   .ABC2     
    \\\\\   \\\\\\
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying do here... this hypothetical example has no relation to excel or vba, as far as I can tell. You need to edit your question with a picture/sample data from **excel**, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and take the [tour]

Comment: VBA does not have tree structures and nodes, but you can mimic them.  Classes, perhaps arrays/collection/dictionary as an implementation, there is a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Custom classes will do the job, it can have a collection to store child objects, which can then also have the same approach to have their own child objects.

Class clsObj

```
Private pChildObjects As New Collection
Private pName As String
Public Property Get ChildObjects() As Collection
Set ChildObjects = pChildObjects
End Property
Public Property Let ChildObjects(value As Collection)
Set pChildObjects = value
End Property
Public Property Get Name() As String
Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(value As String)
pName = value
End Property
```

Used in a sub:

```
Sub GenerateHierarchy()
Dim a As clsObj, b As clsObj, c As clsObj

Set a = New clsObj

a.Name = "Grandfather Bob"

Set b = New clsObj
    b.Name = "Parent A"
    a.ChildObjects.Add b, b.Name

Set c = New clsObj
    c.Name = "Child A"
    a.ChildObjects("Parent A").ChildObjects.Add c, c.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You , Wookies-Will-Code for your response... I had tried using Dictionary object, but code getting too clumsy ( i.e) - - unable to retrieve and display back grand parent -parent - child  clearly in excel.. let me try your suggestions -  have a great day..